# Can SpEL in Spring Integration Router use Java's String class methods

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-http

This is an extension question to [How to use SpEL to read payload and header content in a Spring Integration Router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55303759/how-to-use-spel-to-read-payload-and-header-content-in-a-spring-integration-route)

**Technologies in my project**

```
Spring Boot 2
Spring Integration (XML style)
Java 8
Tomcat 9.x/Liberty 19.0.0.1
```

As a part of my Spring Integration project (REST API with an inbound-http-gateway, that takes an XML input and produces an XML output), this is the setup for my question:

- There is a Builder-pattern-based Java object (say, `MyPOJO`) that is the payload in the flow.
- `MyPOJO` has a String property/instance variable (say, `String response`) along with a getter and setter.
- Somewhere in the flow, `MyPOJO` gets built and `response` gets set.
- Inside `response`, there is a *keyword/specific piece of text* that will determine the further course of the flow.

This said, is it possible to write a Router (using XML configuration) that can check if the `response` inside `Message<MyPOJO>` contains that *keyword/specific piece of text* to determine where to go next?

Illustratively, something like this:

```
<int:router input-channel="inputChannel" expression="payload.getResponse().contains("keyword")">
    <int:mapping value="true" channel="oneRoute"/>
    <int:mapping value="false" channel="anotherRoute"/>
</int:router>
```

When I do this and launch the application, the error is:

```
nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 44; columnNumber: 98; Element type "int:router" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"
```

Specifically speaking, the `expression="payload.getResponse().contains("keyword")"` part seems to be having an issue getting resolved and this could be something to do with the quotation marks around the `keyword`

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Sincerely,
Bharath

Comment: What is the problem are you facing? Doesn't that just work for you as is? I would do the same configuration. What is the point of the question?

Comment: I missed mentioning the actual error @ArtemBilan so the post has been updated now. Please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. I see you have an XML syntax error. The fix is like this:

```
expression="payload.getResponse().contains('keyword')"
```

The `keyword` is in *single quotes*, not *double*.

This is definitely how SpEL works: when you would like to specify a literal in the expression, you need to use single quotes: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions-evaluation